# Software for LASSO for high dimensional dataset

Tags: software, lasso

I have a dataset with between 10,000 and 100,000 feature values. The number of datapoints is between 1,000 and 10,000. I want to perform a LASSO on this dataset but can't really find any good software to do so. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There is a package in R called lars that handles common procedures related to least angle regression and lasso.  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lars/index.html

Comment: Have you looked at the [\[lasso\]](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lasso) tag? There are several relevant questions there.

Answer (score 4):

Check the article by Wu Chen Hastie Sobel Lange - Genome-wide association analysis by lasso penalized logistic regression - 2009. They mention a 'swindle' that is not hard to implement + then you can simply work with glmnet (there is a new version out recently which promises a performance improvement but I haven't had a chance to check it out).

Comment: I know it's an ancient post, but I didn't understand the swindle they used. Could you elaborate?